# Migrating from Windows XP

Tags: upgrade

I'm not sure if this exact question was asked before but here it is.
I am currently on windows xp and would like to move to a version of Linux/Ubuntu like Ubuntu itself or Lubuntu or whatever is out there. Only thing is it should be easy for my parents to use it, as they are not so techie...! It should be kind of similar to xp and should be so buttery smooth.

Here are my current system specs:
Pentium 4 2.8 GHz
20 GB dedicated for OS, whichever it is, rest 20 for personal use (total 40 GB HDD)
RAM 1.4 GB
Graphics 32 MB
Wired internet connection
Should have LTS or whatever it is called - for updates, so that I don't have to update/upgrade for a long time.

Please suggest me the best one with reason.

Comment: See the link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/447319/migrating-from-windows-xp-to-ubuntu  I personally recommend Lubuntu - It has the most XP like appearance of all official Ubuntu distributions. Also you may try Ubuntu MATE (or Linux Mint with MATE environment.)

Comment: Can Ubuntu run on 32mb graphics, like my computer?

Comment: Ubuntu, with its graphic Unity interface, will be slow or not work at all, and 256 mb is recommended. However, Lubuntu may run easily. In any case you will have the opportunity to try it out before you actually overwrite Windows and install something else.

Comment: @Jos - what you both are suggesting is that I install Lubuntu rather than Xubuntu, or Ubuntu. I can skip ubuntu as you said, it might be slow. So..! 
By the way, what is the difference between Lubuntu and Xubuntu?
Which do you both recommend for my specs, and why?

Comment: @Muzaffar - check my post above, since I can't mention both of you at the same time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people migrating from Windows XP **LXDE** or **MATE** desktop enviromments would be the easiest ones to learn as they use very similar appearance.

Consequently Lubuntu (LXDE using OS) or Ubuntu MATE (MATE using OS) will be the best choice.

Xubuntu using XFCE is also worth trying.

The lightest in terms of hardware requirements is Lubuntu. Go for Lubuntu 14.04 - It is the latest stable version which is going to be supported for 5 years. (Until 2019)
Here are the minimum supported requirements of Lubuntu 14.04 according to Ubuntu wiki:

266 MHz processor;
128 MB;
3 GB hard drive;
no fancy graphics

A more usable system would have:

512 MHz processor or faster, 32 or 64 bits;
512 MB of RAM;
6 GB hard drive;
no fancy graphics

Ubuntu MATE 14.04 LTS is also supported until 2019, but not from Canonical. It is not official Ubuntu flavour yet and receives support only from its team.
[Ubuntu MATE 14.04 hardware requirements](https://ubuntu-mate.org/about/)

Xubuntu is another good option for older computers, though it is a bit ''heavier'' than Lubuntu. See here for requirements:  [Xubuntu.org](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/requirements/)

Bear in mind most Linux distros allow you to try the system before installing. When you boot from the installation disc you will have two choices : ***Try*** or ***Install***

You may choose the ***Try*** option to test the OS. You will be able to see if it will be suitable for your hardware and of course your **taste**. Try and choose. And Best Luck with Ubuntu.

Comment: @Muzaffar - Could you tell me if there is any known issues or bugs with Lubuntu or Xubuntu?

Comment: @Jos - Same as posted above

Comment: Well, yes there will be lots of small bugs, which is normal for such a large code base. Fortunately, you can trace them all in one place: http://bugs.launchpad.net. No bug will be so bad that it would be better to avoid the distro altogether.

Comment: @Jos Any themes for making lubuntu or xubuntu look just like XP? Please reply thank you!

Comment: I mean including start menu items and start menu you know what I mean

Comment: I'm no Lubuntu expert but [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/make-lubuntu-look-like-windows-xp/) looks very much like WinXP.

Comment: Also, finally, how is zorin os different from Lubuntu and xubuntu?

Comment: It is also based on Ubuntu. See here for details: http://zorin-os.com/faq.html  It also has lite version based on LXDE like Lubuntu. And here http://www.cupoflinux.com/SBB/index.php?topic=1757.0